# Load data into BigQuery and partition data based on time as well as split by another variable

Tags: google-bigquery

*(I'm very new to databases so please let me know how I can make this question better.)*

I am trying to load multiple files of columnar data into BigQuery from an AWS S3 bucket

- It is web analytics data of over 150 different websites
- There are multiple files, each containing 15 minutes of web analytics data
- Each file contains data for all 150 websites for a 15 minute slot, however there is a column called `site_code` which tells us which site the row pertains to

Here is a snapshot of relevant columns:

```
timestamp_info_nginx_ms site_code action
          1.539168e+12    site_1  event1
          1.539168e+12    site_2  event2
          1.539168e+12    site_3  event1
          1.539168e+12    site_1  event1
          1.539168e+12    site_2  event2
```

The size of data is 200+GB per week and I want to be able to load 12 weeks' data.

**My goal is to minimise monthly query costs.**

**Some context:** My main use case is that I will analyse data for one website (or a group of websites) at a time. Of the 150 sites, I will focus mainly on 10-15 websites. Let's call them *primary websites*. I expect to analyse primary websites on a regular basis (daily) and the rest of the websites occasionally (1-3 times month) or rarely (1-3 times in 2 months).

I have understood that I need to partition my data tables by day. Which looks relatively simple to do via BigQuery GUI.

However, my question is that is it possible to load this data into separate tables for my primary websites (one table for each primary website) and separate for the rest of them?

Comment: btw, did you read https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b?

Comment: Looks promising. That might just be the answer. Thanks Felipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at BigQuery's recently released functionality called clustering, it is exactly what I was looking for. The following lines of code will solve my question regarding the sample dataset.

For this use case I am assuming the data is stored in GCS and that it is ndjson and compressed files.

At the time of posting this answer, it is not possible to create clustered tables via web UI hence I am looking at the command line option, by installing the gcloud sdk.

While it possible to create a partitioned table at the time of loading the data (as in the table creation and loading data into it can be done at the same time) it is not possible (as of now) to simultaneously create a clustered table. Hence this is a two step process where Step 1 is to create an empty table; and Step 2 is to load data into it.

Given my sample dataset my schema will look like this:

```
 [
   {"type": "TIMESTAMP", "name": "timestamp_info_nginx_ms", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"type": "STRING", "name": "site_code", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
   {"type": "STRING", "name": "action", "mode": "NULLABLE"}
  ]
```

Store the above json in current working directory as myschema.json
Note that my partitioning filed is going to be timestamp and my clustering fields are going to be site_code and action. The order in which clustering is done matters. Remember the clustering order when you run queries on this

Create a dataset in BigQuery called my-dataset.

Now call gcloud sdk's bq command in your terminal to create a table.

```
bq mk -t --schema ./myschema.json --time_partitioning_type=DAY --time_partitioning_field timestamp_info_nginx_ms --require_partition_filter=TRUE --clustering_fields='site_code,action' my-dataset.my-clustered-table
```

This should create a new table called my-clustered-table within an existing dataset called my-dataset.

Now load the data into the table using gcloud sdk's bq command in your terminal.

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --max_bad_records=1000 my-dataset.my-clustered-table gs://my-bucket/my-json-files/*
```

This should work.